# Using variable in command path for ExecStart in systemd service

Tags: linux, service, systemd

Im trying to make a systemd service like below :

```
[Unit]
Description=Syslog

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="TESTEXTSERVICESFILES=/opt/test/extservices"
Environment="TESTCONFDATA=/storage/test/conf"

ExecStartPre=/bin/echo ${TESTEXTSERVICESFILES}/syslog/bin/nxlog $TESTCONFDATA
ExecStart=/opt/test/extservices/syslog/bin/nxlog -c ${TESTCONFDATA}/syslog/nxlog.conf
#ExecStart=/${TESTEXTSERVICESFILES}/syslog/bin/nxlog -c ${TESTCONFDATA}/syslog/nxlog.conf


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After running '*sudo systemctl daemon-reload ; sudo systemctl start test-syslog ; sudo systemctl status test-syslog*', I get the following success output:

```
● test-syslog.service - TestSyslog
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/test-syslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Fri 2018-02-23 10:15:09 UTC; 11ms ago
  Process: 9474 ExecStart=/./opt/test/extservices/test-syslog/bin/nxlog -c ${TESTCONFDATA}/test-syslog/nxlog.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9471 ExecStartPre=/bin/echo /.${TESTEXTSERVICESFILES}/test-syslog/bin/nxlog $TESTCONFDATA (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9474 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/test-syslog.service
           └─9478 /./opt/test/extservices/test-syslog/bin/nxlog -c /storage/test/conf/test-syslog/nxlog.conf

Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: test-syslog.service: control process exited, code=exited status=0
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: test-syslog.service got final SIGCHLD for state start-pre
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: About to execute: /./opt/test/extservices/test-syslog/bin/nxlog -c ${TESTCONFDATA}/test-syslog/nxlog.conf
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: Forked /./opt/test/extservices/test-syslog/bin/nxlog as 9474
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: test-syslog.service changed start-pre -> running
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: Job test-syslog.service/start finished, result=done
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: Started Test Syslog.
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: Child 9474 belongs to test-syslog.service
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: test-syslog.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
Feb 23 10:15:09 lt-x260-1606.test.local systemd[1]: test-syslog.service changed running -> stop-sigterm
```

Here the service has started successfully. But when I comment the first ExecStart directive and uncomment the second one I get 
as failure :

```
● test-syslog.service - Test Syslog
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/test-syslog.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-23 10:11:44 UTC; 11ms ago
  Process: 9243 ExecStart=/$TESTEXTSERVICESFILES/test-syslog/bin/nxlog -c $TESTCONFDATA/test-syslog/nxlog.conf (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 9239 ExecStartPre=/bin/echo /.${TESTEXTSERVICESFILES}/test-syslog/bin/nxlog $TESTCONFDATA (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9243 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 23 10:11:44 lt-x260-1606.test.local echo[9239]: /./opt/test/extservices/test-syslog/bin/nxlog /storage/test/conf
```

This time the service cannot start, like it doesnt want to start the process starting by ${TESTEXTSERVICESFILES} variable. Does someone have any idea why it is not working even if command lines are the same in both cases ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't use variables in the actual command. [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines):

> The command to execute must be an absolute path name. It may contain
>   spaces, but control characters are not allowed.

You might wan't to wrap it in a shell command (which does parameter expansion):

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/${TESTEXTSERVICESFILES}/syslog/bin/nxlog -c ${TESTCONFDATA}/syslog/nxlog.conf'
```

Comment: In my case, I had to add `exec`: `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'exec $VAR'`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Environment=`, use `EnvironmentFile=`, to define multiple environment variables.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/customsyslog
ExecStart=/bin/echo ${TESTEXTSERVICESFILES}/syslog/bin/nxlog $TESTCONFDATA
```

`/etc/sysconfig/customsyslog` would contain `key=value` pair, e.g.,

```
TESTEXTSERVICESFILES=/opt/test/extservices
TESTCONFDATA=/storage/test/conf
```

Comment: Yeah I know I was just trying to make this test service works before :)

Answer (score 0):

An old message that I've just stumbled on but looks like your ExecStart line that doesn't work may have 2 '/' at the beginning. One from the ExecStart line before the variable and one from the variable which is declared as /opt/test/extservices
Just a thought.